# merge selected text lines from .txt and remove unwanted lines

Tags: regex, batch-file

I have a .txt of around 27000 text lines looking like this:

**Path to file 1**
    File type for file 1
    File extension for file 1
    File creation date for file 1
    File modification date for file 1
   **Page Count for file 1**
    Author for file 1
   **Path to file 2**
    File type for file 2
Page Layout
    **Page Count for file 2**
    File extension for file 2
    File creation date for file 2
    File modification date for file 2
    Author for file 2
   **Path to file 3**

and so on for about 5000 files ...

Please help me find an easier way (batch if possible) to sort the line so the output would look like this:

**Path to file 1**    **Page Count for file 1**
   **Path to file 2**     **Page Count for file 2**

because currently I am using an automation software to analyze each line and from what I estimate it will take 20 hours to complete the job.

Comment: Can you show an example of your actual data? Also, is this on Windows?

Comment: I can tell you from experience that stream readers will operate on large text files much more quickly (often 100 times more quickly) than parsing with `for` loops and similar.  This looks like a job best suited for `awk` I think.

Comment: You have not provided specs as to your file format - your description does not show any pattern in the data. So it is impossible to determine how to parse out the required information (as a human, let alone any program)

Comment: Can you provide a real sample with 3 repetitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Batch file below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "filepath="
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "Path Count" input.txt') do (
   if not defined filepath (
      set "filepath=%%a"
   ) else (
      echo !filepath! %%a
      set "filepath="
   )
)
```

... run using *the same example data* you provided in your question, produce this output:

```
Path to file 1 Page Count for file 1
Path to file 2 Page Count for file 2
```

... that is *exactly the same output* you requested.

Before you post a comment similar to: "This program does not work with my real data!", you should realize that you had **NOT** posted your real data and we have not a crystal ball that allow us to guess it...

*If you want precise answers, you should post precise questions!*